# How to write a postgresql query for getting only the date part of timestamp field, from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to write a postgresql query for getting only the date part of timestamp field, from a table

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
select DATE(my_field) from my_table;
```

Answer (score 27):

You have two basic options, each with a number of equivalent expressions.  Assuming a TIMESTAMP field named `"ts"`, you can extract the date part:

- By [type cast](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)

  - `CAST(ts AS DATE)`
    SQL-compliant syntax
  - `ts::DATE`
    Historical pg syntax
  - `DATE(ts)`
    Actually a function.  Note that *this syntax is deprecated*, per the link above.
- By [date/time function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

  - `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ts)`
  - `DATE_PART('YEAR', ts)`

Comment: Thanks for robust answer and deprecation warning! Casting it is.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to cast your timestamp to a date:

> SELECT
>
> > CAST('2010-01-01 12:12:12' AS date)

Answer (score 0):

Following way work for me

CAST(to_timestamp(timestamp_value/1000) AS date) as created_date